Specify None as default value for Boolean function argument?
The prototype for numpy.histogram contains an input argument density of type bool and default value None.  If the caller does not supply density, what value does it take on?
The closest Q&A that I can find is this.  The first answer says "Don't use False as a value for a non-bool field", which doesn't apply here.  It also says that bool(x) returns False, but that doesn't assure the caller that the function will set density to False if it isn't provided.  Is this a mistake in the documentation of the prototype for numpy.histogram, or am I missing something about the documentation convention?
The other answers to the above Q&A do not seem relevant to my question.

...it takes on the value None, the default. That's also false-y; it's only used here.

Remember that Python is not strongly typed.  Those type hints have no effect at all at runtime.  They're just for editors and linters.  You can pass a string for that argument, and the language will allow it, although the function itself might object.  Also remember that EVERY object in Python has a boolean value.

@TimRoberts Python is strongly typed. I guess you wanted to use the word "static" instead.

It's set to None; the fact that an explicit argument should be Boolean doesn't change that.

@johrsharpe & Tim Roberts: The cited Q&A explains what falsy is, but is it an established convention that Boolean arguments with default None will always be set according to their truthy-ness and falsy-ness, and not some other scheme that seems logical to the developer? Thanks for the reminder that type hints are suggestions, but this is a question about convention.  Can I expect input arguments documented as bool to undergo truthy/falsy conversion before use. I'm trying to rule out some home cooked conversion to bool when I view documentation in general.

@chepner: "It's set to None; the fact that an explicit argument should be Boolean doesn't change that". So we either *assume" that the variable is set according to truthy/falsy-ness or we dive into the code to confirm?  There is no established convention as to the intent?

I'm not quite sure what you're expecting here.  We know from the declaration that the parameter will be used in a Boolean context.  The default value, None, has a clearly defined meaning when used in a Boolean context.  No "conversion" is needed.

This is at best poorly documented. The documentation seems to imply that False and the default None will be treated equivalently, but it should either document that explicitly, or use the more sensible False as the default value. (The third option would be if the function makes a distinction between False and None, but that also should be explicitly documented.)

Thanks, chepner.  It sounds like there is no established convention that a documented bool argument with default None will be converted to False.  We assume this at our peril or dive into the code to confirm.  I'll wait a bit before marking this as the answer.

There is no such convention, because making a three-way distinction between True, False, and None would be a reasonable thing to do.

From the method's source code, we can see that the density argument is only used at the end of the method in an if statement.
In Python, None is interpreted as False (is is a falsy value). This means that providing None to numpy.histogram's density argument is equivalent to providing it with False.
I suppose that the developers found it more appropriate to use None instead of False for a value that has not been defined by the user.

Thanks for plumbing the source.  I added a comment to my question to clarify that I'm asking about whether it is an established convention on which I can rely when viewing documentation in general, i.e., a documented argument of type bool will be undergo truthy/falsy conversion rather than some other conversion scheme that might make sense to the developer and largely behave like truthy/falsy-ness (except in corner cases).

I am pretty sure that it is not an established convention. I dived a bit deeper in the source code and found that there used to be a normed argument along with the density argument.

The normed argument was deprecated and eventually replaced by density, but the two coexisted for a while.
They used a default value of None to know if one of the two arguments was specified by the user but no the other. You can have a look at how it was done here.
So the default value of None seems to be for historical reasons and should probably be replaced by False...

Thanks for the explanation for that weirdness!
